# TreeSet with date strings

Tags: java, treeset

I have a `TreeSet<String>` that contains date strings in the following format: `2014-07-02`.

Do I understand it correctly that this format will enforce chronological order of the dates in the set?

Comment: Yes. (filler, as 15 characters are not needed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will.

It is commonly used as a prefix for files in a directory so they can be ordered *by date* while ordering them *by name*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your strings are yyyy-mm-dd, then yes, they would be in chronological order.

Answer (score -1):

If  Chronological order = a record of events starting with the earliest and following the order in which they occurred!!!

then its not in that order.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<String> set= new TreeSet<String>();
    set.add("2014-06-04");
    set.add("2014-06-03");
    set.add("2014-08-02");
    for(String s: set)
    {
        System.out.println("set: "+ s);
    }

output:
 set: 2014-06-03
 set: 2014-06-04
 set: 2014-08-02
```

correct me if i am wrong